# How do I give one entry point a file name with a hash but not any others?

Tags: webpack

I have a webpack config that looks like this:

```
  entry: {
    app: './public/javascripts/app.js',
    /* ...like 10 more entry points here... */

    //I want this one to have a hash in the filename
    newThing: './public/javascripts/newThing.js' 
  },
  output: {
    path: outputPath,
    publicPath: '/public/',

   //I can't [hash] here because it would break all the existing filenames
    filename: '[name].built.js',

    chunkFilename : '[name]-[chunkhash:6].built.js'
  }
```

I want my `newThing` entry to get a `[hash]` in the filename. But that `output` config seems to apply to all your entry points uniformly. Basically I want a different set of filename substitutions for one entry than the others. Any way to accomplish this with Webpack (v3 ideally)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename), `output.filename` can be a string or a function. So you should be able to do something like this:

```
filename: function(obj) {
  if (obj.name === 'newThing') {
    return 'newThing.' + obj.hash + '.js';
  } else {
    return obj.name + '.built.js';
  }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly this throws errors for me although it is in the docs. Asked about it on the PR on github here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/6144

Comment: Doh! Sorry. Yeah looks like it didn't make 3.10.0